# How to access an element of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with a number of keys and I want to store each element of a key as a lists of lists.

```
dict = {'d': [[5.5, 42, 'p1'], [3, 17, 'p2'], [3, 8, 'p3'], [2.8, 3, 'p4']],
        'm': [[4.2, 12, 'p5'], [4.8, 25, 'p6'], [4.3, 3, 'p7'], [8.9, 29, 'p8']],
        's': [[8.6, 42, 'p9'], [9.7, 46, 'p10']],
        'g': [[4.3, 56, 'p11'], [5.1, 8, 'p12']]}
k=[]
for i in range(len(dict)):
    k.append(dict['d'][i])
print k
```

- Expected output: `[[5.5, 42, 'p1'], [3, 17, 'p2'], [3, 8, 'p3'], [2.8, 3, 'p4']]`
- Current output:  `[2.8, 3, 'p4', [5.5, 42, 'p1'], [3, 17, 'p2'], [3, 8, 'p3'], [...]]`

Please suggest something or at least point me in the correct direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The existing answers already solve your problem in a better way, but I wanted to point you to the mistake you've made: if you had used `range(len(dict['d']))` instead of `range(len(dict))`, you would have gotten the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are using a loop, but the value you need is the value of *key* `d` in `dict`. You may access it like:

```
>>> my_dict = {'d':[[5.5,42,'p1'],[3,17,'p2'],[3,8,'p3'],[2.8,3,'p4']],'m':[[4.2,12,'p5'],[4.8,25,'p6'],[4.3,3,'p7'],[8.9,29,'p8']],'s':[[8.6,42,'p9'],[9.7,46,'p10']],'g':[[4.3,56,'p11'],[5.1,8,'p12']] }

>>> my_dict['d']
[[5.5, 42, 'p1'], [3, 17, 'p2'], [3, 8, 'p3'], [2.8, 3, 'p4']]
```

**Note:** Do not use `dict` as variable name, as it is built-in type in Python

Answer (score 1):

Just use index-access:

```
k = dict['d']
```

or if you want a copy of the list:

```
k = dict['d'][:]
```

Comment: k=dict['d'][:]
using this i get the following output
[[5.5, 42, 'p1'], [3, 17, 'p2'], [3, 8, 'p3'], [2.8, 3, 'p4', [5.5, 42, 'p1'], [3, 17, 'p2'], [3, 8, 'p3'], [...]]]
instead of 
[[5.5, 42, 'p1'], [3, 17, 'p2'], [3, 8, 'p3'], [2.8, 3, 'p4']]